# Ionic get tabs working in a side menu app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 1.3, and I have built a side menu app.

In on of my page, I want to have Tabs to display 3 different pages.

Here is my code (app.js) :

```
//MAIN
  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "views/app/side-menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

//PROFIL
  .state('app.profil', {
    url: "/profil",  
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "views/app/profil/tabs.html",
      }
    }
  })

//PROFIL TAB 1
  .state('app.profil.tab1', {
    url: "/tab1",    
    views: {
      'tabProfilContent': {
        templateUrl: "views/app/profil/tab1.html",
        controller: 'ProfilCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

And here's my tabs.html view :

```
<ion-view class="profile-view">
  <ion-nav-title>
    <span>Votre profil</span>
  </ion-nav-title>
<ion-header>
<div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
    <div class="tabs">
      <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="app.profil.tab1">
        Tab 1
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="app.profil.tab2">
        Tab 2
      </a>
      <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="app.profil.tab3">
        Tab 3
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-header>

<ion-nav-view name="tabProfilContent"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-view>
```

It works, but, is there a way to set the status of tab ? The tabs are not active while I change Tab. Is this the correct way to achieve it ?

Comment: For a tabs like app, you'll have to setup an abstract state (default page) for tabs. Which means, setup one of these three tabs as default landing tab and define routes for them. For details, checkout documentation on ionic's website